# Jmeter save 90% response time

Tags: jmeter, response, beanshell

Is there a way to save the 90th percentile response time using Beanshell PostProcessor once all the requests have been executed?

The only way that I know how is to save the response time of each sample using "getTime", and then add a Beanshell to calculate it. Is there some other way? Maybe accessing a specific variable class that gives us this out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

I **do not know** how to do this using Beanshell PostProcessor. I'm using [BM.Sense Uploader](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LoadosophiaUploader/) (**It's a JMeter Plugin**) which is a helpful listener to me. It's very simple to use.

**Here is a screenshot after a test:**

[image]

From the above image in the "**Aggregate percentiles**" sections, you can easily get **90th percentile response time**.

Comment: Am looking to capture it in BeanShell. Do you happen to know how to do that?